# building custom minimal linux from source.with cross compiling toolchain,etc.error fixdep.o.cmd:1:missing separator. Stop--Makefile error or something

Tags: linux, makefile, compiler-errors, linux-kernel, cross-compiling

I cross compiled toolchain now building linux kernel. I followed this page

https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/diy-build-custom-minimal-linux-distribution-source

So I compiled all the tools including gcc, etc. When I reached compiling `linux-4.16.3` kernel, with this command

```
  make ARCH=${LJOS_ARCH} CROSS_COMPILE=${LJOS_TARGET}- INSTALL_MOD_PATH=${LJOS}
```

I got following error

```
root@this:/home/ubuntu/source/linux-4.16.3# CHK     include/config/kernel.release
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
  CHK     include/generated/bounds.h
  CHK     include/generated/timeconst.h
  CHK     include/generated/asm-offsets.h
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  DESCEND  objtool
Makefile:49: warning: overriding recipe for target '/home/ubuntu/source/linux-4.16.3/tools/objtool/'
Makefile:46: warning: ignoring old recipe for target '/home/ubuntu/source/linux-4.16.3/tools/objtool/'
/home/ubuntu/source/linux-4.16.3/tools/objtool/.fixdep.o.cmd:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.
make[3]: *** [Makefile:43: /home/ubuntu/source/linux-4.16.3/tools/objtool/fixdep-in.o] Error 2
make[2]: *** [/home/ubuntu/source/linux-4.16.3/tools/build/Makefile.include:4: fixdep] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:63: objtool] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:1687: tools/objtool] Error 2
```

Now apparently it looks like the makefile in `/home/ubuntu/source/linux-4.16.3/tools/objtool/` has something wrong at line `line 43,and line 63`

OR while running the `scripts/checksyscalls.sh` it struck with something that causing problem. Like something that the scrip is doing but that `command not found` I am completely clueless what might causing problem. No idea. In the link above the author downloaded busybox, so I believe it had something that needed to be installed but I didnt.

I like someone please explain what the error means and why is this causing

Thanks for help...

Comment: The separator is usually a <TAB> . ..... A 'missing separator' can mean that a line starts with the text, or with <space><space>text  ..... ..... instead of a <TAB>

Comment: see https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/linux-kbuild/patch/2d0bd4a4-98cb-380e-36c4-e46dc5d53991@molgen.mpg.de/